# How does an op amp compare voltage?

Tags: voltage

How does an op-amp know where the ground is because the inputs are single wires, how does an op-amp compare them to a ground like this circuit for example

[image]

clearly the op-amp is not connected to ground

Comment: Why do they have to be compared to ground and not just to each other?

Comment: Measure a battery voltage with a meter and it gives you the voltage without referring to ground.

Answer (score 1):

By subtracting one input from the other the reference point (ground) cancels out
$$\underbrace{V_1 + V_0}_{\text{positive input}} - \underbrace{(V_2 + V_0)}_{\text{negative input}} = V_1 - V_2.$$
So the reference voltage does not affect the output.

This is done with the so called differential pair.
[image: differential pair]

Answer (score 0):

It won't, it will compare signals appearing its (+) and (-) terminals, always.
At B, half of 9 V is appearing. At point A, I am guessing T is a variable resistor, so the signal at A will depend on T's value. Clearly, this circuit is intended to compare signals which are not zero or ground.

If you want it to compare one signal to ground or (zero), you have to make one signal ground or zero.

Though, why need to compare it to ground? It will result in the signal itself or op-amp output will always be High since there is +9V at one input.